# Find folders and delete contents

Tags: command-line, bash, files, delete, find

I want to find all folders that have a particular name and then delete all contents but not the folder...

This is to find the folder:

```
find /home/ -type d -name 'myname'
```

Now how to delete all contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `exec` option to start a shell which gets the list of files to remove:

```
find /home/ -type d -name 'myname' -exec bash -c 'rm -i "$0"/*' {} +
```

This will ask you for every single file to remove which is always a good idea if you don’t want to lose data, but if you know what you’re doing you can remove the `-i` flag from the `rm` command.

Answer (score 1):

use `cd` to move to the directory (folder) containing the items you want to delete, and then use `rm` to delete contents. Refer to the manual entry for rm for more usage information: `man rm`